# How to use combineLatest with filter in certain observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, pipeline, redux-observable, combinelatest

This is a simplification of a complex case, where some observables in array could be filtered if the values are not valid. The problem is that the filtered observable is not allowing to the other complete the combine. What operator or approach could handle this case allowing the valid data log in the subscription?

```
// RxJS v6+
import { fromEvent, combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, startWith, scan, tap, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

const userData$ = [
   of({ name: 'Joseph', age: 23}), 
   of({ name: 'Mario', age: 33}), 
   of({ name: 'Robert', age: 24}), 
   of({ name: 'Alonso', age: 25})
];

const names = ['Joseph', 'Mario', 'Robert', 'Alonso'];

combineLatest(
  names.map((name, i) => {
     return userData$[i].pipe(
         map(({name, age})=> { return{ name, age: age * 2} }),
         filter(({age}) => age < 67),
         map(({name, age})=> { return{ name: name.toLocaleUpperCase(), age} }),
     )
 })
)
   .pipe(
     tap(console.log),
   )
   .subscribe();
```

[Sample in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-okajnz?file=index.ts)

If we change the value to 67 all the observables will show the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical problem with `combineLatest` is that it requires all source Observables to emit at least once so if you use `filter` to discard its only value then `combineLatest` will never emit anything.

An easy solution is to make sure it always emits with `defaultIfEmpty`:

```
combineLatest(
  names.map((name, i) => {
    return userData$[i].pipe(
      map(({name, age})=> { return { name, age: age * 2} }),
      filter(({age}) => age < 66),
      map(({name, age})=> { return { name: name.toLocaleUpperCase(), age} }),
      defaultIfEmpty(null),
    )
  })
)
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rsffbs?file=index.ts

If your real use-case uses other source Observable than `of()` that doesn't complete immediatelly you might want to use `startWith` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `combineLatest` with `from` as `combineLatest` won't emit if either one of the item in stream array doesn't emit

```
const userData$ = [
  { name: 'Joseph', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Mario', age: 33 },
  { name: 'Robert', age: 24 },
  { name: 'Alonso', age: 25 }
];

const names = ['Joseph', 'Mario', 'Robert', 'Alonso'];

from(
  userData$
)
  .pipe(
    map(({ name, age }) => { return { name, age: age * 2 } }),
    filter(({ age }) => age < 66),
    map(({ name, age }) => { return { name: name.toLocaleUpperCase(), age } }),
    tap(console.log),
  )
  .subscribe();
```